# Redirecting URL with variable in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

Whats the recommended method for redirecting with variables in Zend Framework?

Lets say we have an action like this within a controller:

```
 public function newAction()
    {
        $form = new Form_ApplicationForm();
        if($this->_request->isPost()){
            $data = $_POST;
            if($form->isValid($data)){
                $appModel = new Model_Application();
                $result = $appModel->createApplication($form->getValue('name'),
                    $form->getValue('email'),
                    $form->getValue('comments'));
                if($result){
                    // redirect here 
                }
            }else{
                $form->populate($data);
            }
        }
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
```

If i wanted to redirect to a URL where i could show something like:

> "Thanks for your application, your
>   reference is #123"

How should i perform this redirect?

something like this maybe?

```
$this->_redirect('/application/confirm/'.$result);
```

If so then how would i access the `$result` var?

**EDIT** OR I guess this would work:

```
$this->_redirect('/application/confirm/?id='.$result);
```

.. but i'm not sure if this is best practice or not?

I've seen examples where people use `_forward()` for their redirects but the URL never changes which creates issues with multiple submissions etc.

I've seen someone recommend `gotoSimple()` but i'm not sure about this. Still a ZF noob so apologies if this is obvious but I guess this is something with multiple uses for CRUD type systems anyway so would be interested to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*A lot* of options. Your controller's `$this->_redirect()` delegates the work to `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector`. Check its [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector) for all the options, and pick the one you like. Simplest ways not involving custom routes:

```
$this->_redirect('/controller/action/param1/value1/param2/value2');
```

or

```
$this->_redirect(
    '/controller/action',
    array('param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2')
);
```

You're right in paying attention to the difference between `_redirect` and `_forward`. Forwarding means just re-routing the initial request, while `_redirect` really causes an HTTP redirect.

Comment: thanks for the info, one thing i'm not sure about though is in your first example, how can param1 and param2 be accessed as they are nowhere in $_REQUEST?

Comment: I see its available through $this->_request->getParam('param1'), is this the recommended method?

Comment: Request's getQuery([string $key = null], [mixed $default = null]) returns the members of $_GET superglobal. getParam will also work, but it returns more than just $_GET entries.

Answer (score 1):

Not to over-simply, but have you considered putting it in `$_SESSION`, and then just reading it on the next page?

Page 1:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 10;
```

Page 2:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['foo']);
```

Comment: dont like using session variables for things like this, feels too hacky and means it cannot be bookmarked. Really i want the variable to be in URL, i guess i can just do something like $this->_redirect('/application/confirm/?foo='.$result);